# Conversion of a String to a latitude and longitude using google maps in PHP

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

I have this code that should show me Marker in Google map:

```
var latitudine='<?echo php $_POST['lat']; ?>';
    var longitudine='<?echo php $_POST['lon']; ?>';
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(latitudine,longitudine);
   function initialize()
   {
    var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myCenter,
  title:'Click to zoom'
  });

 marker.setMap(map);

 // Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
  map.setZoom(15);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

But when I visualize the map, i haven't the marker. In which way can i transfer the values "Latitudine" and "Longitudine"?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Threw out my entire previous answer. Looks like you did the echo syntax wrong:

```
var latitudine='<?echo php $_POST['lat']; ?>';
var longitudine='<?echo php $_POST['lon']; ?>';
```

should be

```
var latitudine='<?php echo $_POST['lat']; ?>';
var longitudine='<?php echo $_POST['lon']; ?>';
```

Comment: My problem is that map doesn't take the correct values of latitude and longitude (it takes both values 0.0), so it doesn't show me the correct marker, despite database contains right values.

Comment: You're using something that's been posted from a form, in what way is that related to the DB?